# Abstract method in PHP 7.0.1

Tags: php, windows, windows-server-2012, php-7

Recently, I've upgraded a long-running application to PHP 7.01 (32-bit) together with Apache 2.4.18 on a Windows Server 2012.

Since then, I get entries like the following inside the PHP error log:

> `[Sun Jan 03 11:52:18.582829 2016] [:error] [pid 12604:tid 1092]
>   [client 93.132.169.26:64219] PHP Fatal error: Class
>   wbb\\data\\thread\\ThreadList contains 1 abstract method and must
>   therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (SeekableIterator::C:\\php) in
>   C:\\Websites\\zeta-producer.com\\community\\lib\\data\\thread\\ThreadList.class.php
>   on line 15`

This happens inside a German community software called "[Woltlab Burning Board 4.1](https://www.google.com/search?q=Woltlab%20Burning%20Board)" (WBB).

The vendor claims that this is a bug in my PHP version, since `SeekableIterator::C:\\php` is not a valid method name.

Coming from a .NET background I'm unable to judge the vendor's claim.

**My question:**

Can anyone give me some hints about this? Does this really look like a bug in PHP and not in WBB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question:

I've install [PHP 7.0.2 RC1](http://windows.php.net/qa/) which seems to fix this behavior.